# How do you created a shared folder within Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm studying a code sample from a reference book. 
The author assumes I know how to create a shared folder.

[image]

I don't.

How do I create a share folder within the Project Navigator where I can share resources/codes amongst targets?

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, all the files in your Xcode project can be shared amongst targets.
You don't need to do anything specific. The folder name `Shared` is a little bit misleading here.

You need to look for the target membership panel in this view:

[image: enter imajust selectption here]

To do it, just select a file inside code navigator, then press `cmd-alt-1` and inside this menu, you will have file based settings for target memberships that look like this:

[image]

You can also choose multiple files to change their target settings accordingly.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.2  I tried Command-Alt-1 (one) and didn't get anything.  Is there a menu equivalent I can choose?

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee Updated with a new screenshot

Comment: Okay... thanks for the update.   It appears the 'shared' folder is a misnomer as you mentioned.  However I notice this particular folder has a darken 'wedge' in the lower left corner of the icon vs a plain folder.   Don't know the significance.